# How to Send Email from wordpress website using PHP and without any plugins?

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp, gmail

Am a Dot Net Developer.I know how to send emails in Dot Net and thats quite easy.Recently I started learning wordpress and unfortunately strucked at the beginning itself just because of e-mail sending process.

I Read many article and answers as well from stackoverflow.Everywhere in a php `mail()` function they are showing the few parameteres (i,e; email_from.email_to,subject,...etc according to syntax of `mail()` function.)As a developer i know that it is required to give the password to authenticate for sending email.**Where to give that password?**.

I tried lot of ways following different people words. I put all smtp details along with password in `php.ini` file andalso tried in `wp-config.php` file.
But no use Am not getting any error in the application and even am not getting mail sendiing too.

So now my question is to please let me know the process of setting application to send email using **mail()** function without any plugins.

And is there any way to debug the php website using breakpoints with any app?
Please help me to learn.
-Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the Wordpress itself can send mail messages such as notification or "Forgotten Password" messages and they are all using the 'mail()' function. If you are encountering an issue that displays that the 'mail()' is not working, then either:

- You do not have the SMTP Enabled on your hosting environment (which happens on free hosting plans);
  or
- You need to create a email address 'wordpress@domain.com' where you replace the '@domain.com' with your domain of course.

With the information above your Wordpress will be able to send it's (system/notification) messages without any issues, but if you wish to send Normal mail messages using the Wordpress I am afraid that is not possible without a Plugin.

Comment: I wnated to send email from my own email address (belongs to gmail.com)

Comment: Most hosting companies make that if you use a different email address than 'wordpress@domain.com' it will trow a 'mail()' issue, to use a different email address I would then strongly suggest using a Plugin unfortunately not achieving your starting goal.

Comment: Using PHP Mailer service i have achieved sending email from wordpress using php and google smtp